# multiplicative inverse in factor ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, inverse

If I need to find the multiplicative inverse of an element in some $T[x]/(m)$ factor ring, do I need to solve a diophantine equation to get the solution?

Let the element be $f$. Then $fu \equiv 1$ (mod $m$) so $fu-mv=1$. Is this correct? $u$ is the inverse

Comment: It basically amounts to the working through the reverse Euclidean algorithm for polynomials (pretty much the same process one would find the multiplicative inverse of an integer $m \in \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. (What you've said so far is correct).

Comment: @user128576 what you wrote is correct, but knowing something about T might provide a shortcut. Anything special about T?

Comment: it might be C or some Zp

Comment: As you've noted, computing an inverse in $\,T[x]/m\,$ is equivalent to solving said diophantine equation in $\,T[x].\,$ If $\,T$ is field then $\,T[x]\,$ has a division algorithm so Euclidean algorithm for the gcd, so the extended Euclidean Division Algorithm may be used to compute the inverse ([see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) for a convenient method to do so).